# How to write update query for updating multiple rows into single sql query in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I want to write update query for updating multiple rows into single SQL query in Objective-C.

Does anyone knows how i can achieve that ? Please help.

**Here is my update query:-**

```
UPDATE chatDetailTable SET threadId = '584140258203930624', createdByFirstName = 'Poonam', createdByLastName = 'Deshpande', createdById = '201', createdByImgUrl = '', createdByRole = 'teacher', msgType = 'text/plain', msgText = '1111', canEdit = '1', deliverOn = '2017-03-30T12:23:20.73Z', thumbUrl = '', isOwned = '1', replies = '0', mediaPath = '', isFailed = '', read = '1', isSeen = '0', key = '', gmid = '', contact_id = '2', recipientFirstName = 'Indrajit', recipientLastName = 'Joshi', recipientId = '2', recipientImgUrl = '', recipientRole = 'user', isGroup = '0', threadStatus = 'open', mediaUrl = '(null)', status = 'pendingApproval', reviewedById = '0', broadcastId = '584140258136821760' WHERE msgId = '584140258203930625';UPDATE chatDetailTable SET threadId = '584140258266845184', createdByFirstName = 'Poonam', createdByLastName = 'Deshpande', createdById = '201', createdByImgUrl = '', createdByRole = 'teacher', msgType = 'text/plain', msgText = '1111', canEdit = '1', deliverOn = '2017-03-30T12:23:20.73Z', thumbUrl = '', isOwned = '1', replies = '0', mediaPath = '', isFailed = '', read = '1', isSeen = '0', key = '', gmid = '', contact_id = '4', recipientFirstName = 'Hrusikesh', recipientLastName = 'Desai', recipientId = '4', recipientImgUrl = '', recipientRole = 'user', isGroup = '0', threadStatus = 'open', mediaUrl = '(null)', status = 'pendingApproval', reviewedById = '0', broadcastId = '584140258136821760' WHERE msgId = '584140258266845185';UPDATE chatDetailTable SET threadId = '584140258266845186', createdByFirstName = 'Poonam', createdByLastName = 'Deshpande', createdById = '201', createdByImgUrl = '', createdByRole = 'teacher', msgType = 'text/plain', msgText = '1111', canEdit = '1', deliverOn = '2017-03-30T12:23:20.73Z', thumbUrl = '', isOwned = '1', replies = '0', mediaPath = '', isFailed = '', read = '1', isSeen = '0', key = '', gmid = '', contact_id = '1002', recipientFirstName = 'Pramod', recipientLastName = 'Agarwal', recipientId = '1002', recipientImgUrl = '', recipientRole = 'branchAdmin', isGroup = '0', threadStatus = 'open', mediaUrl = '(null)', status = 'pendingApproval', reviewedById = '0', broadcastId = '584140258136821760' WHERE msgId = '584140258333954048';
```

Comment: please post your table data structure so we can help you out.

Comment: I have posted my update sql query in question, Please check

Comment: Which data you want to update in multiple row ? please clear your question ? as in your query there are lot of filed which you are updating.

Comment: I want to update all fields which i have specify in my update query.

Comment: multiple rows but on which base? i mean which field

Comment: @SunilPrajapati  i am getting multiple values through API.
if my primary key is exist in table then i need to update the all columns except the one column.

Comment: you want to update multiple rows with different multiple value?

Comment: @SunilPrajapati YES
But i want to update that in single query

Comment: i think it's not possible in query you need no of times call update query

Comment: you can make one function with updateQuery parameter and reuse them for all

Comment: and call function with different query with values

Answer (score 0):

Based on your query you have to set all values with column name and update without any `WHERE` condition so it will update all row available in your table with provided new value.

```
UPDATE chatDetailTable SET threadId = '584140258203930624', createdByFirstName = 'Poonam',
```

Not include column which you don't want to update.

If you want different different value on every row so based on your API response you need to loop your data and update it by `primary_key` condition.

```
NSMutableArray *serverResponse;

for (NSDictionary *dictObject in serverResponse) {

    NSString *strUpdateQry = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"UPDATE chatDetailTable SET threadId = %@, createdByFirstName = %@ Where id = %@",dictObject[@"threadId"],dictObject[@"FirstName"],<PRIMARY_KEY>];
    //Execute Update qry with database classes.
}
```

In above code you need to pass your data dynamically and generate UPDATE query with some primary key and execute it with your DB classes.

**Syntax :** `The basic syntax of UPDATE query with WHERE clause is as follows: UPDATE table_name SET column1 = value1, column2 = value2...., columnN = valueN WHERE [condition]; You can combine N number of conditions using AND or OR operators.`

Hope this will helps to update your table.

Comment: she want to update multiple rows with different multiple value. your answer update all rows with same values

Comment: Yes @SunilPrajapati I have Updated my answer based on Savita's comment,

Comment: yes but still wrong my bro, it's update all rows not few rows of them.
example, only 4rows want update out of 10 than your answer may be wrong

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

You can update only rows you want updating

```
"update TableName set fieldName1 = 'value1', fieldName2 = 'value2', fieldName3 ='value3' where id IN(1,2,3)"
```

**IN : it update only 1,2 and 3 id's rows only**

Hope it work for you

Comment: i want to update multiple rows with different values.